# Dynamically adding new fields resets values in previous fields

Tags: javascript, html

I using an HTML / Javascript combination to add fields dynamically.

Here is the jsfiddle for it: http://jsfiddle.net/kM9Yg/2/

My problem is, if I input values in a field, and then click on the Add More button, a new field gets added but the previous fields' values get reset.

The button to add more is of type `<input type="button"/>` and not `<input type="reset" />`

Any way to prevent this?

Comment: I just checked in jsfiddle, The values are not reset after I click "Add More" button. I chose some values from drop down and click "Add More" button. The values were not reset in previous fields. Can you please explain your problem in detail? Correct Me If misunderstood.

Comment: @SelvakumarP: What browser are you using? I'm using Chrome 15 and they reset for me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use DOM methods, not innerHTML. DOM methods are standardised, innerHTML is not. Some browsers will reflect the current value as the default value, others will not.

You can do:

```
var el, oEl = document.getElementById('divToClone');
if (oEl) {
  el = oEl.cloneNode(true);
  // code here to fix duplicate ids and
  // set style.display = '' so it's visible

  oEl.parentNode.appendChild(el);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. That was some good info. Wasn't aware innerHTML wasn't a DOM method.